# In TFS, can you include another test suite in a query-based suite?

Tags: testing, tfs, test-suite

In a TFS query-based suite, is it possible to include all test cases contained in another test suite?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Query from **Flat List** to **Tree of Work Items** then set the query to something like this:

[image]

Use the clauses in the *top* query to limit it down to the Test Suite you want - in my case, the one called `New suite`.

Comment: This does not return any test cases for me